# sass-globbing в Webstorm

Tags: ide, sass, webstorm

В моем проекте имеется файл **main.scss**, в него через директиву    `@import blocks/**/*.scss";` при помощи sass-globbing подключаю остальное. 
Все файлы в директориях `block/**/` начинаются с символа нижнего подчеркивания, соответственно file watcher моей IDE не производит компиляцию файла main.scss при изменении содержимого в тех файлах.

Проблема отсутствует если не использовать sass-globbing, но в виду огромного количества файлов неудобно каждый раз импортировать новый файл в проект.

Как заставить IDE проводить компиляцию всего проекта принудительно?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте поиграть с аргументами вотчера.

По умолчанию там подставляется

```
--no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

Я предполагаю, если `$FileName*$` поменять на `main.scss` и `main.css`, то при изменении любого наблюдаемого файла должна проходить обновление всего.